# How to elegantly convert a RDBMS bottom-up hierarchy into an OO top-down hierarchy?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dictionary

In my RDBM i have modeled a Folder-like structure as a table that references itself:

```
table Folder {
   Name : String
   Parent : Reference(Folder)
}
```

in my UI-Code I need to bring this into an Object structure of this kind:

```
class Node(String name) {
   String name;
   List<Node> children;
}
```

What is the best (most readable, performant, stable, ...) way to convert Database results into a code structure?

```
List<Folder> bottomUpFromDb = [SELECT Name, Parent FROM Folder];
List<Node> topDown = convert(bottomUpFromDb);
```

**How would you implement `convert(List<Folder> databaseRows)`? I played around with Maps and recursive functions for a while but I am stuck.**